# What is the meaning for area="frontend" in email_templates.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email-templates

Today I am checking the email_templates.xml and found 1 thing which is not getting me.

```
<template id="customer_create_account_email_no_password_template" label="New Account Without Password" file="account_new_no_password.html" type="html" module="Magento_Customer" area="frontend"/>
```

Here what is the meaning of `area="frontend"`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Area Code is a component that organizes code with the aim of
  **optimizing query** processes. Only code that is defined in a **specific** Area Code is fetched in a given situation. This helps, for example, to optimize REST queries. What is rendered is not the
  entire HTML, but only what is **absolutely necessary** to answer a
  REST query.
- The way Area Codes operate is best visualized when **creating
  routers**.
- **Routers cannot be defined globally –** they have to be contained within a **given Area Code**. What this means is that we can create
  two routers with an identical path and the framework will know, by
  itself, which Area Code we have in mind (due to the fact that routers
  start with a different path depending on where they are located).
- `Di.xml` files can be defined in a `catalogue` (globally) or in
  subfolders, the names of which reflect the names of specific Area
  Codes.
- These could be, for example, ‘`frontend`’, ‘`adminhtml`’ or
  ‘`webapi_rest`’. Plugins and observers can also work globally or for a
  specific Area Code only.

  ---

**Magento is organized into these main areas:**

**Magento Admin** (adminhtml):

```
 - entry point for this area is `index.php` or `pub/index.php`. The Admin
   panel area includes the code needed for store management. The
   `/app/design/adminhtml` directory contains all the code for components
   you’ll see while working in the Admin panel.
```

**Storefront (`frontend`):**

- entry point for this area is `index.php` or `pub/index.php`. The
  storefront (or `frontend`) contains template and layout files that
  define the appearance of your storefront .

**Basic (base):**

- used as a fallback for files absent in `adminhtml` and `frontend` areas.

**Cron (crontab):**

- In `cron.php`, the `\Magento\Framework\App\Cron` class always loads the
  ‘`crontab`’ area.

You can also send requests to Magento using the `SOAP` and `REST` APIs.
These two areas

---

**Web API REST (`webapi_rest`):**

- entry point for this area is `index.php` or `pub/index.php`. The REST
  area has a front controller that understands how to do URL lookups
  for REST-based URLs.

**Web API SOAP (`webapi_soap`):**

- entry point for this area is `index.php` or `pub/index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Magento 2 has the following areas:

```
 - admin
 - adminhtml
 - catalog
 - crontab
 - doc
 - frontend
 - global
 - setup
 - webapi_rest
 - webapi_soap
```

The purpose of area is efficiency. So that your code gets called only when it's required in that area, for example your code will be called only while frontend functionality is executed not while admin side functionality is being executed even when your template file **email_templates.xml** is loaded at the backend.

Comment: so you mean If i create a customer account I will not receive any email? also this email_templates.xml it is under etc directory

Comment: Yes if you are creating a customer from the backend and this area is set as frontend. I am not sure exactly how exactly your code is written, but basically that is the functionality.